# How to write Base Url in Dot Net Nuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

If my base url is

```
www.mysite.com
```

- with a DNN site, how do I write this?? (I know this seems simple, but a google search did not show how to write this...

i.e.

```
<a href="{{ my base url }} /games.aspx">Games</a>
<a href="{{ my base url }} /toys.aspx">Toys</a>
```

Comment: DNN is a CMS.  It should already be managing the base URL for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the PortalAlias via the PortalSettings if you ASCX file inherits from PortalModuleBase

```
PortalSettings.PortalAlias.HTTPAlias
```